# How to print/cout unprintable/control characters in c++?

Tags: c++

I have string which contains unprintable/control characters -

```
\222!,\306G6qh\341Pp\210;\241\2619}\222+"\340\315\364ƅ\344\264\215\230\3130ZG!\214\344y\307W(\254Y^\213F\234oz\263V^\274\2453 L
```

The value of this string comes from a function and is different every time the program is run.

Is there any way I can `printf`/`cout` this string ?

Comment: This looks like unicode?

Comment: use **escape characters**

Comment: can you explain @jbutler483 ??

Comment: look into: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Comment: pretty much in order to print a backslash, for example, you need to put another backslash in front of it ( like  \\ will print \ ). There are loads of others too!

Comment: @jbutler I don't think he's talking about escaping a couple of control chars in string literals

Comment: cout << "string = \n " << b << "\n";
What should i add in this line of code ?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is that not the reason its not printing? Due to these escape characters throughout the string?

Comment: @jbutler Not really no :)

Comment: Please list the code.  The answer will be dependent on the type of string, how it is used, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Simply print them as hex, something like this [with EDIT from feedback]:

```
#include <ctype.h>

for( char c : str )
    if (isprint(c))
        if (c = '\\')
            std::cout << "\\\\";
        else
            std::cout << c;
    else
        std::cout << "\0x" << std::hex
            << static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
```

Comment: This is the output - ffffff97ffffffe7ffffffd9Tffffff9ciOffffff81|ffffffb0fffffffd2 fffffff4;ffffffd0fffffff6ffffffd7ffffff90ffffff99ffffffe7ffffffcaffffffb817-fffffff6ffffffa4ffffff8affffff8c_peP|ffffff92ffffff97yV#ffffff82.........(still not that readable)

Comment: This format is ambiguous (what happens to an actual substring "[1]"?) but you're on the right track. Backslashes are fairly ubiquitous for resolving this -- just be sure to make them a special case such that `c == '\\'` results in "\\\\" as output. Casting directly to `int` is also unwise...

Comment: @Ashish That is not the output.

Comment: I tried this but still its unreadable. That's really getting confusing...
Can you give an example code ????

Comment: @AshishGogna replace `static_cast<int>(c)` with `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the string and, for each character, if it's within the range of what you consider "printable", print it. Otherwise, output some alternative representation of your choice; perhaps a backslash followed by a three-digit octal number representing the character's value in integer form.